# How do I get Axios to get data from multiple sources simultaneously without data mixing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

When I try to run multiple simultaneous axios operations of getting data from different data sources using a loop, the data received gets mixed, and therefore corrupted.

I tried creating a different axios instance for each data source, but even still, it seems axios global parameters seem to overwrite individual instance URLs, as far as I can tell.

I've written a simplified example of what generally reproduces the problem:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const axiosObjs = {};

async function get_data(dataSetName) {

    let dataToSave = [];

    if (!axiosObjs[dataSetName]) {
        axiosObjs[dataSetName] = axios.create({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://example.com/dataSets/',
        });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const urlString = 'https://example.com/dataSets/' + dataSetName + "_" + i;

        const dataSetChunk = await axiosObjs[dataSetName](urlString)
            .then(result => result) 
            .catch((err) => { return "this is just a simplified example"; });

        dataToSave = [].concat(dataToSave, dataSetChunk.data);

        await wait_milliseconds(500);  // made up function, waits half a second
    }
    
    save_data_to_file(dataSetName, dataToSave);  // made up function, saves data to file
}

// these all result in data mixed up between saved data sets
get_data("dataSet1");
get_data("dataSet2");
get_data("dataSet3");
```

The resulting files include data mixed up from each data source, apparently because the loops are happening simultaneously where each iteration of the loops overwrites each other's parameters within the separate function calls.

How can I get around this without having to run `get_data` as separate synchronous calls?

Comment: Have you tried using a single axios instance instead of creating multiple?

Comment: The point of `axios.create` is to create an instance of axios with a *reusable* config so you don’t need to repeatedly set it. You’re overriding the whole config immediately after setting it so you might as well not bother. It would be simpler to just use `axios.get('https://myDataSets.com/dataSets/' + dataSetName + "_" + i)` instead of the first 11 lines of your loop.

Comment: Note that GET requests may not have a body and you aren’t even trying to set a body on them, so adding a Content-Type  header claiming that the body which doesn’t exist is JSON makes no sense at all.

Comment: Eyeballing this, I can’t see any way that the data would get mixed up. It might help if you provided more debugging data. Since mydatasets.com doesn’t appear to be a useful website, I guess you’re using it as an example (please use example.com for that, that is what it exists for!) but I’d be focusing on the possibility of a server side problem here, not a client side one.

Comment: @Konrad — Each call to `get_data` has its own `dataToSave` variable / array that is local to the function.

Comment: @e.pacciani yes, I was originally using just one axios instance and setting its parameters each time, but it presented the same problem. This is why I tried shifting over to multiple axios instances, but that didn't solve it.

Comment: @Quentin one of the reasons I'm pretty sure it's axios and not the server is because this problem didn't happen with the same code but using the nodejs "api" (npm api) library. The reason I changed it to axios is because api's newer request "timeout" feature wasn't working correctly, and axios's was.

Comment: @Quentin I edited the original post to clean up the code a bit as per your code suggestions above.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, and it actually was embarrassingly neither axios nor server-related.

The problem stems from the single const keyword I put in bold within the below example (explanation underneath the example):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const axiosObjs = {};

async function get_data(dataSetName) {

    let dataToSave = [];

    if (!axiosObjs[dataSetName]) {
        axiosObjs[dataSetName] = axios.create({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://example.com/dataSets/',
        });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const urlString = 'https://example.com/dataSets/' + dataSetName + "_" + i;

        **const** dataSetChunk = await axiosObjs[dataSetName](urlString)
            .then(result => result) 
            .catch((err) => { return "this is just a simplified example"; });

        dataToSave = [].concat(dataToSave, dataSetChunk.data);

        await wait_milliseconds(500);  // made up function, waits half a second
    }
    
    save_data_to_file(dataSetName, dataToSave);  // made up function, saves data to file
}

// these all result in data mixed up between saved data sets
get_data("dataSet1");
get_data("dataSet2");
get_data("dataSet3");
```

When I created the simplified example to post on StackOverflow, I included the `const` keyword when defining the `dataSetChunk` constant. But in the actual code, I accidentally did not include that `const` keyword, and JavaScript being JavaScript, it just went ahead and made `dataSetChunk` a global variable. Of course, it being a global variable meant that all the simultaneous function calls shared that same variable while populating the data from the server.

Comment: Adding `'use strict'` at the top of the file should force running in strict mode which would throw errors when you try to use undeclared variables

Answer (score 0):

```js
const axios = require('axios');

async function get_data(dataSetName) {
  let unordered_data_chunks = [];
  let promises_to_await = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let data_source_url = 'https://example.com/dataSets/' + dataSetName + "_" + i;

    let promise = axios.get(data_source_url)
      .then((res) => {
        let data_chunk = {
          index: i,
          data: res.data
        };
        unordered_data_chunks.push(data_chunk);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // Do something to handle error.
      });

    promises_to_await.push(promise);
  }

  await Promise.all(promises_to_await);

  let ordered_data_chunks = unordered_data_chunks.sort(
    (a, b) => a.index - b.index
  );

  let data = ordered_data_chunks.reduce(
    (accumulator, current_value) => {
      accumulator.push(current_value.data);
      return accumulator;
    },
    []
  );

  save_data_to_file(dataSetName, data);
}

get_data("dataSet1");
```